# Can I put structured data into an Active Domain record

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

I am building a web front end that will read several databases to show data to the logged-in user.  The user may only see their own data.
The logged-in user is authenticated using an Azure Active Directory.

The user's data is spread over several systems (the users do not have log-in rights to these legacy systems).  In each system the user's records are identified by a userID.  This is different for each system.

In Azure AD (or on prem if needs be) can I add all the system userIDs into the Domain record for the User?
And are there any C# objects to allow me to read this data?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could, but don't.  It's simpler to authenticate the user then pull in artifact claims from a separate database.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions for how to add and access extensions via graph api.